# How do I prove that the square faces on a Rhombicosidodecahedron do not have edges which touch?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

The wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicosidodecahedron) says that the square faces of this shape do not have edges which touch. In other words, the edges square faces do not share edges.

How would I prove this without showing a picture of the solid? I have a feeling it has something to do with Euler's formula ($F+V-E=2$) but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: What is your definition of rhombicosidodecahedron?

Comment: This is kind of a odd question because it really depends on how you define/construct the rhombicosidodecahedron. I think the most natural way to define it would be to describe it by it's faces and how those faces are glued together to form a solid, in which case your claim is trivially true by construction. Do you have an alternative definition/construction in mind?

Comment: No, I really don't. This question actually solves a small part of a larger question  which I am trying to answer, which is: 'how many vertices are on the solid?' And this is just one of the cases that I have to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of rhombicosidodecahedron is "a semiregular (Archimedean) polyhedron such that at every vertex two squares, a pentagon and a triangle meet, in a well defined order", then it is quite obvious that the order must be pentagon-square-triangle-square. If not, the sides of a pentagon should border alternatively with a square and a triangle, but a pentagon has an odd number of sides, so that is not possible.

Comment: How does the number of sides of a pentagon matter?

Comment: Well, suppose a square borders with the first side of the pentagon, then a triangle must border with the second side, a square again with the third side, another triangle with the fourth side, a square with the fifth side, after which, having completed a round, there should be a triangle bordering with the first side… but we started with a square there, so it is not possible.

Comment: Due to the fact that an alternating sequence doesn't work, the pentagon must be bordered only by squares? Why not by triangles?

Comment: Oh, I see. Never mind. Thanks!